# Обработка данных по формуле энтропии Шеннона

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, статистика, scipy

помогите пожалуйста по формуле энтропии Шеннона[image: формуле энтропии Шеннона] обработать массив  [данных](https://yadi.sk/i/JytrvbOsIuHGsA).

Comment: Привет! Непонятно, что значит "обработать" - высчитать энтропию данных? Для этого нужно, во-первых, определиться с валидными данными (столбец "Архангельск" - это данные или нет?), таким образом, будет понятно, что у нас `j`, во-вторых, посчитать распределение вероятностей `pij` (если без углубления в прикладную статистику - к примеру, эмпирическое распределение), затем посчитать саму формулу.

Comment: @hoefling да, столбец "Архангельск" это данные, столбик i- это номер недели, столбик j- год. то есть в одной строке находится информация о названии города, годе, номере недели, числе заболевших и общем числе населения.

Comment: В формуле Шеннона `p(i)` - вероятность наступления события `i`. Где в ваших данных вероятность наступления события? Можно ли считать `sick/total` - вероятностью заболеть в данный промежуток времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [scipy.stats.entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html):

```
In [1]: fn = r"D:\download\Данные с 1990 по 201915.xlsx"

In [2]: df = pd.read_excel(fn)

In [3]: from scipy.stats import entropy
```

[Информацио́нная энтропи́я](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F):

```
In [4]: entropy((df["sick"] / df["total"]).dropna())
Out[4]: 10.952899140178578
```